# Shell script: Finding out a string in each line of a log and send email

Tags: linux, shell, aix

I have a log file which has lines like below.

```
10.10.205.100 100.10.56.5 - [23/Oct/2012:15:30:01 +0000] "GET /way/?cb=777:Obj.Status&log=signing_in_service&cache=1350334642666 HTTP/1.1" 200 53 "https://www.sample.com/signin?off=undefined&questions=&nouser=&link=%23&country=origin&displayLayer=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2" "PD_STATEFUL_d64f218a-fa6a-11e0-b7df-623c1eeb9903=%2Fgateway; PD-ERR=0x132120c8; PD-HOST=sample.com; PD-REFERER=https://www.sample.com/profile%3Fundefined%3D; PD-REFPAGE=signin_user; pSite=; __SIGNIN=signin%23cw%3D400%3Ach%3D321; mmcore.pd=916254201%7CAgAAAAoBQvp/zPBKCBGRP6QBAOZMgV9Kf89IAAsAAAAtzSlGSn/PSAAAAAD/////AEoIAQAAAAAAAQAAAAAA////////////////AAAAAAABRQ%3D%3D; mmcore.srv=cg4.use; mmid=-1116944464%7CAgAAAAr6f8zwSggAAA%3D%3D; mmcore.tst=0.155; PD-SGNPAGE=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sample.com%2Fcommon%2Fregister%2Feproxy.html; UnicaNIODID=A3nRYVRjMyy-Xv66UJt; survey=1350334587161"
```

I am trying to get the http status code which is 200 in the above line. This will be placed after the string HTTP/1.1". Version of http (here it is 1.1) may not be common in all the lines.

Based on the status code (if its not 200 and few other status), i have to send an email along with the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you have after `HTTP/` is the http version number. There are not many versions of http (http 1.0 and http 1.1). So this wil work:

```
 awk -F"HTTP/1.[0-9]\" " '{print $2}' filename | cut -d' ' -f 1
```

Comment: Thank you.. This helped me to pull all http codes. Now from each line i have to pull out the values and write a condition to send an email. Let me try and get back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -o 'HTTP/[0-9.]\+" [0-9]\+'` to get just the portion from HTTP up to the number. What goes after the space is the number, so just add `| cut -f2 -d' '`.

Answer (score 1):

(I am assuming that you only want to mail the offending line and not the whole logfile.)

If the number of spaces prior to the status code are always the same, then you can check the ninth field using `awk`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# find-bad-lines

# Match only statuses that do not start with 2 or 3
# (i.e., 4xx and 5xx)
awk '!match($9, /^[23]/)'
```

Then you want to process each "bad" line by piping the output of `find-bad-lines` into `handle-bad-lines`

```
#!/bin/bash
# handle-bad-lines

while read -r line
do
    # This is where you could execute a script for email
    echo "$line"
done
```

It would look like this:

```
$ find-bad-lines <logfile.log | handle-bad-lines
```

Obviously you would want to add error handling and stuff; but, this is the basic idea.

Comment: thank you.. but number of spaces prior to the status code are not always same. ll make use of awk code from the first answer.